# Expected number of draws from an urn (without replacement) to get 2 different coloured balls

Tags: expected-value

An urn has $N=18$ black balls and $M=2$ white balls. What is the mean number of balls one must draw to get two different colours. My solution so far is extremely ugly (though effective):

$$\mathbb{E}_{N,M} = \sum_{k=1}^N{(k + 1)\left(\prod_{i=1}^k{\frac{N + 1 - i}{N + M + 1 - i}}\right)\frac{M}{N + M - k}} +
\sum_{k=1}^M{(k + 1)\left(\prod_{i=1}^k{\frac{M + 1 - i}{N + M + 1 - i}}\right)\frac{N}{N + M - k}}$$

I tried to map this problem to use a [negative hypergeometric distribution](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution), but had no luck. Can we use it? Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

---

Using Mathematica (and assuming $N$ and $M$ are positive integers), one can simplify the expression to:

$$1+\frac{N}{1+M}+\frac{M}{1+N}$$

Though I fail to grasp the intuition behind this.

Comment: See the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/110456

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use the negative hypergeometric distribution to solve that problem. When drawing from a population of $N$ elements without replacement where $K$ of them are successes, the mean number of successes you'll draw until you draw $R$ failures is given by:

$$
f(N,K,R) = E[x \sim NHG_{N,K,R}] = R ~ \frac{K}{N-K-1}
$$

Back to your problem. Consider two cases: one in which the first ball drawn is black (p = 18/20) and the other in which the first ball is white (p = 2/20). You can then calculate your average for each case and weigh them as follows:

$$
\frac{18}{20} ~ f(19, 17, 1) + \frac{2}{20} ~ f(19, 1, 1) + 2
$$

The last term refers to the first draw (which is considered separately) and the last "failure" draw, which is not counted by the negative hypergeometric distribution.